# Angular 6 Calendar with multiple date selection

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

my question is very simple, I need to show a calendar and let the user pick multiple dates - e.g. 1/2/2018, 1/3/2018, 1/4/2018. That is, not a range, but multiple dates.

In Angular 1.x, I used the [Calendar Component MultiSelect](https://github.com/spongessuck/gm.datepickerMultiSelect) directive on top of UI Bootstrap to accomplish this.

I am not able to find such solution for Angular 2+, either using ng-bootstrap some other library. Any points will be much appreciated.

My question is if anyone knows any component that meets this requirement, or how can I have the behavior I want with a known calendar such as ng-bootstrap?

Many thanks!

Comment: Questions asking for component/library recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Excuse me, I did not know, but I do not know where else I can find an answer.

Comment: I usually just google terms like "Angular multi-date datepicker" or similar. Or start with angular material's datepicker and extend it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this component is suitable for your need.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiple-date-picker-angular

Comment: Do you have a working example on stackblitz for example ?